# RAG - how to deal with numerical data

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, llm

I have a car marker companies data . I am creating chunks for different car models in llama index and using vector store index and it is giving decent outputs when asked questions . It fails poorly when i ask questions like suggest car models below $xyz . I have tried many embedders but problem is that it language model doesn't seem to have sense of amounts/price and it matches against more expensive models . In general , how do you deal with such cases . Do you use llama index tools to deal with numerical questions . Please guide and let me know if more details are required